# Creating objects from strings

Tags: java, introspection

So I've read in some data from an XML:

```
String arg1Value;
String arg2Value;
String arg2TypeAsString;
String arg1TypeAsString;
```

and I want to create an object: `ObjectType(arg1Type, arg2Type);`

I'm trying this:

```
(ObjectType) Class.forName(arg1TypeAsString).getConstructor(arg1Type.class, arg2Type.class).newInstance(arg1Value, arg2Value)
```

But this gives me a `noSuchMethodException: ObjectType.<init>(arg1Type, arg2Type)`

Note that I'm trying to create different objects but they all extend from ObjectType and all their arguments extend from arg1Type and arg2Type respectively.

Comment: Google search revealed this-- I'm a C# guy so I can't help you myself: http://www.rizzoweb.com/java/dynamicInstantiation.html

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the value of `arg1Type` and `arg2Type`? What does the `ObjectType` class look like?

Comment: @Raniz the argTypes can be different, sometimes double, string; or other things like int, string. ObjectType is an abstract class, but I want to make objects of the classes that extend from it

Comment: So does `ObjectType` with constructor `ObjectType(arg1Type, arg2Type)` exists or not?

Comment: @FilipBulovic no, but I have several classes that extend from ObjectType, all those classes take arguments that extend from arg1Type as the first argument and an argument that extends from arg2Type as it's second argument.

Comment: If you are trying to create class which doesn't exist or missing method which you are attempting to invoke than rather use ASM to create what you need and after that go for reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Given the specifications are a bit vague (no actual code), try the followings:

1. Make sure your constructor does not have `private`, `protected` or default package modifier, if so, use `getDeclaredConstructor()` instead
2. Define a default constructor for `ObjectType` class
3. Split your statement on multiple lines:

   ```
   Class<ObjectType> otClass = (ObjectType) class.forName(arg1TypeAsString);
   Constructor<ObjectType> otConstructor = otClass.getConstructor(arg1Type.class, arg2Type.class);
   ObjectType ot = otConstructor.newInstance(arg1Value, arg2Value);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

My initial assumption was that `newInstance` should be called with array of objects. This is not correct, see comment below. Then likely reason is that you are passing primitive type to `newInstance` for example `int` instead of `Integer`. Naturally creating array of Objects will eliminate such possibility. Finally I managed to replicate error message by removing constructor from my target class so it couldn't be found

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Foo.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

Please take a look at all those exceptions which implementation throws. Please create your `ObjectType` compile it and place it in classpath so it could be found.
Here is my implementation of method returning `Object` which you can cast to desired type

```
static Object createInstance(String clsName, String ctorType1, String ctorVal1, String ctorType2, String ctorVal2)
      throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, 
      IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    return Class.forName(clsName).getConstructor(Class.forName(ctorType1), Class.forName(ctorType2))
        .newInstance(new Object[]{ctorVal1, ctorVal2});
  }
```

It is tested and works. Quite few exceptions to catch. You may want to adjust parameter types so they fit your design requirements. This is my test class

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo(String in, String out){}
}
```

Comment: This is not OP's problem. [`Constructor.newInstance(Object... initargs)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) is a varargs method so no need to explicitly create the `Object` array.